# Why size of Vercel storage continues growing up

Tags: postgresql, vercel

Few days ago I build a very small personal blog based on Vercel serverless functions and Vercel Postgres. After running  fews day everything is okay expect I found the storage size is way over limit (900M+ / 256M) and it's continuously growing (about 1MB every a few minutes).

[image: capture]

Each table should only store very few text data. There are less than 100 recrods added up all tables. Checking the database sizes does not identify problems too.

```sql
select DATNAME from "pg_database";
# postgres
# template1
# template0
# verceldb
select pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('postgres')); # 7184 kB
select pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('template1')); # 7064 kB
select pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('template0')); # 7064 kB
select pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('verceldb')); # 7528 kB
```

How could I figure out what happened and how to fix it?

Comment: Without knowing what "Storage size = 907 MB / 256 MB" actually measures I don't know that anyone can say. Assuming "vercel" are a company providing this service, what do they say about it?

Comment: @RichardHuxton This question has already been marked as `vercel`-related and yes, _Vercel is the platform for frontend developers. Vercel has zero-configuration support for 35+ frontend frameworks and integrates with your headless content, commerce, or database of choice_. Nothing helps from its [doc](https://vercel.com/docs/storage/vercel-postgres/usage-and-pricing#storage). I sent a feedback but they didn't response yet. So I posted this question in search of someone has encountered this problem for help.

Comment: I'm not sure if the way they calculate database capacity is as expected. The database should only store less than 1MB of data.